# Why does my GUI window freeze whenever ActionListener is performed?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, networking

I am sending a string message of "5" via Client 1 to the server whenever a button on the GUI window is clicked and the server receives the message and sends it to the other client, Client 2, connected to the same port as Client 1. When the button is clicked, the Client 2 does receive the string message "5", but the problem is that as soon as the button is clicked, the whole GUI window of Client 1 freezes (not being able to click on anything). The same goes for the Client 2, which does the same thing of sending a string message of "2" when the button is clicked, but the GUI window also freezes when the button is clicked. Why is the GUI windowing freeze?

Code snippet:

```
BufferedReader buffR;
Socket sock = new Socket(nameHost, portNum); 
PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream()); 
this.buffR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        printW.println("5");
        printW.flush(); 
    }
});
```

Edited - Additional Code Snippet (Receiving portion):
This is a runnable method that's inside a thread class along with the code snippet above.

```
public void run() { 

    try{
        while(true){

            String line = br.readLine(); 
            int update = Integer.parseInt(line);
            current-= update; //int current = 0 and update is the number received from the other client, which is "5"

            JLabel newNumber = new JLabel(current); //Assign the newNumber JLabel with the current number

            jp.remove(number); //Remove the JLabel 'number' which initially shows "50" 
            jp.revalidate();
            jp.repaint();
            jp.add(newNumber); //Replace the JLabel 'number' with 'newNumber'

            if(update == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Reached 0", "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    } catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("ioe in ChatClient.run: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think a while (true) loop does? When does it stop?

Comment: How many action listeners do you need exactly?

Comment: @JBNizet I would like to have the two clients continue to interact with each other by sending messages via pressing buttons so I put it as a while loop. How could I fix it in a way that the interaction is continued until its terminated?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Just two, but how could I fix it in a way that the interaction between two clients is continued until either of their windows is terminated?

Comment: @user3466314: yes you'll need a loop to get information from the PrintWriter information, but not to continually add ActionListeners as that way lies madness. I'd read from the BufferedReader in my loop, and then display the results in the GUI (but taking care to display the Strings in a Thread-safe way). I'd use a SwingWorker to help me do this.

Comment: Your edit just invalidated my answer. :( Please re-edit, but add the new code and question at the bottom and leave the original question text and code intact.

Comment: Now you've deleted most of your question -- why? I've rolled it back to its previous state. Please don't do this as it is not fair to the volunteers of this site who put in time to try to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Your `while (true)` is being called on the Swing event thread, tying up the the thread and preventing it from performing its actions of drawing the GUI and interacting with the user. Also you're adding the ActionListener multiple times which makes little sense since each ActionListener will be called when the button is pressed.

Solution:

1. Get rid of that unnecessary and dangerous while loop.
2. Read up on [Swing Threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and then strive to abide by the rules.

---

Note that if you need to continuously read from your BufferedReader object, then yes, place the reading of it inside of a `while (true)` loop, but don't add any ActionListeners or make any changes to the state of your Swing objects from inside the loop. Instead I'd use a SwingWorker object, have my `while (true)` loop inside of its `doInBackground()` method so that it is sure to run in a background thread, and then I'd update the display of the GUI using the SwingWorker's publish/process method pair so that the Strings are pushed into the GUI in a thread-safe way. The link I've given you above will help you to achieve this.

---

**Edit**
Your code could look something like:

Setting up the button's ActionListener

```
  // add this ActionListener once and only once
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // get the line of text from the GUI
        String text = myTextField.getText();

        // send the text out to the socket via the PrintWriter
        printW.println(text);
     }
  });
```

Note that better would be to use an AbstractAction, and then set the JButton and the JTextArea's Action using the same object.

The accepting side of things would involve using a SwingWorker to allow us to use blocking code, `buffR.readLine();` without blocking the GUI. Note that all code in the `doInBackground()` method is done in the background thread and off of the Swing event thread, the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread):

```
  // use a <Void, String> SwingWorker since I want to publish a String
  new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (true) {

           // read in a String from the BufferedReader in background thread
           String line = buffR.readLine();

           // publish String so it can be used on Swing event thread, the EDT 
           publish(line);
        }            
     };

     // this code is called in the Swing event thread, the EDT
     protected void process(java.util.List<String> chunks) {
        for (String line : chunks) {
           // display text in my JTextArea
           myTextArea.append(line + "\n");
        }
     };
  }.execute();
```

Comment: Well I only would like for them to send the message when the button is pressed, but at the same time, I would like for them to be able to interact with one another via sending messages with the button. When the button is first pressed, it does interact with the other client and reflects on the other client's GUI, but as soon as that's performed, the window with the button pressed freezes. If I get rid of the while loop they won't be able to continuously interact with one another while the windows aren't terminated?

Comment: @user3466314: see edit to answer. I can tell you that you will only achieve madness by trying to add an ActionListener repeatedly inside of the loop. Just don't do it.

Comment: I checked it out but I don't understand how actionListener would allow the user to continue to press the button to send the message "5" to the server without being inside the loop. It seems like the one provided will just allow the user to press the button only once to send the message.

Comment: @user3466314: you seem to misunderstand how ActionListeners and event driven programming works. When you attach an ActionListener to a JButton, the listener code gets called every time the button is pressed. Putting it into a loop doesn't call the listener code multiple times, but instead it adds a bunch of unnecessary listeners to the button.

Comment: Ah got it! So I just took out the while(true) loop out of the code I provided in the original post and started the Client 1 and Client 2 and connected both of them to the server. I pressed the button on Client 1 and it sent the message "5" and it reflected on Client 2's window, and the Client 1's GUI window page didn't freeze and the buttons are pressable-looking, but it won't send the string message of "5" anymore. What could be the problem now?

Comment: @user3466314: difficult to tell based on the information available.

Comment: @user3466314: 1) You ignored my comment to your original question. Again, your edit invalidates my answer which is not a nice thing to do to me. 2) Your code ignores Swing threading rules as outlined in my link to the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial. 3) Why are you removing and adding JLabels? Why not just change the text held by a single JLabel? 4) You need to try to create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or something close to it if we're to understand your code and your problem.

Comment: Sorry! I just thought that they were examples, because yours use JTextField whereas I use a JLabel, where I can apply to my own code, which I did thanks to you by removing the while(true). Is my code in run() ignoring the Swing threading rules? Could you elaborate, because I took a look at it but still have a difficult time understand sadly... also how could I just edit the text held by a single JLabel, like JLabel 'number', for example.